# Is there a Julia equivalent of the targets R package?

Tags: julia, pipeline, reproducible-research, targets-r-package

The `targets` R package lets the user define an execution pipeline with minimal extra syntax and automatically handles things like cache and random seeds. It would be nice to have a similar tool in Julia.

Closest thing I have found so far is DrWatson.jl but it seems a lot more limited in scope.

Comment: would this work? https://github.com/cihga39871/Pipelines.jl

Comment: I will have to look deeper into it, but reading through the documentation, it looks quite promising. Thank you!