# `_targets`/Pipeline frameworks in Julia?

Tags: julia, target

I am new to Julia and wondering if there is a similar pipeline framework than R's _targets. The aim is to document the steps of a given study and run it effectively (rerun only outdates scripts). Or what is the common way to store the results?

Thanks in advance,
M

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; however, I am not looking for "|>" pipes. With regard to the pipeline framework, I am referring to a system wherein dependencies for created objects can be managed, and the entire pipeline can be run, with only the updated parts being rerun.

Comment: Maybe `Pipelines.jl` ?

Comment: Maybe [DrWatson.jl](https://juliadynamics.github.io/DrWatson.jl/stable/#Functionality-1) has a little bit of intersection with it?

Comment: This is not a Julia answer, but [dvc](https://dvc.org/) might be of interest.

Comment: Have a look at: [Is there a Julia equivalent of the targets R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76636394) .